# How to Handle the 'DeadlockLoserDataAccessException'?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

```
org.springframework.dao.DeadlockLoserDataAccessException: StatementCallback; SQL [ Update m_loan_arrears_aging inner join m_loan ml ON ml.id = loan_id  SET ml.`loan_sub_status_id`=  CASE  WHEN (@tempVariable:= DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),overdue_since_date_derived)) > 0 and (@tempVariable) <= 15 THEN 801  WHEN (@tempVariable)>15 and (@tempVariable) <=30  THEN 802  WHEN (@tempVariable)>30 and (@tempVariable) <=60  THEN 803  WHEN (@tempVariable)>60 and (@tempVariable) <=90  THEN 804  WHEN (@tempVariable)>90 THEN 805  ELSE NULL  END  WHERE  loan_id=210 and ml.loan_sub_status_id !=100 OR ml.loan_sub_status_id IS NULL ;]; Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction {stmnt 1971232613  Update m_loan_arrears_aging inner join m_loan ml ON ml.id = loan_id  SET ml.`loan_sub_status_id`=  CASE  WHEN (@tempVariable:= DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),overdue_since_date_derived)) > 0 and (@tempVariable) <= 15 THEN 801  WHEN (@tempVariable)>15 and (@tempVariable) <=30  THEN 802  WHEN (@tempVariable)>30 and (@tempVariable) <=60  THEN 803  WHEN (@tempVariable)>60 and (@tempVariable) <=90  THEN 804  WHEN (@tempVariable)>90 THEN 805  ELSE NULL  END  WHERE  loan_id=210 and ml.loan_sub_status_id !=100 OR ml.loan_sub_status_id IS NULL ;} [code=1213, state=40001]; nested exception is org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction {stmnt 1971232613  Update m_loan_arrears_aging inner join m_loan ml ON ml.id = loan_id  SET ml.`loan_sub_status_id`=  CASE  WHEN (@tempVariable:= DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),overdue_since_date_derived)) > 0 and (@tempVariable) <= 15 THEN 801  WHEN (@tempVariable)>15 and (@tempVariable) <=30  THEN 802  WHEN (@tempVariable)>30 and (@tempVariable) <=60  THEN 803  WHEN (@tempVariable)>60 and (@tempVariable) <=90  THEN 804  WHEN (@tempVariable)>90 THEN 805  ELSE NULL  END  WHERE  loan_id=210 and ml.loan_sub_status_id !=100 OR ml.loan_sub_status_id IS NULL ;} [code=1213, state=40001]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:263)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:413)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:546)
    at org.apache.fineract.portfolio.loanaccount.service.LoanArrearsAgingServiceImpl.updateLoanArrearsAgeingDetails(LoanArrearsAgingServiceImpl.java:234)
```

I have tried to solve this issue by annotation called @Synchronized. It works for me but it took a lot of time to complete the execution. So I tried Asynchronous annotation But i don't know how to configure it

Comment: You have a deadlock on the database. What's the cause?

Comment: This is due to the concurrency problem.
The second query getting exception while the first query in execution process in the same table.

Comment: But there must be more than one table involved to get a deadlock. One is not enough. Is there something else updated?

Comment: I have already mentioned that this is due to concurrency problem So there is only one table and two API calls at the same time.